# npm install: Error : Cannot find module 'tough-cookie'

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I have removed and reinstalled node.js many times

```
> node -v
4.5.0
> npm -v
3.3.6
```

Once I run the command `npm install request` I get the following error :

```
Error: Cannot find module 'tough-cookie'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Generic User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\lib\cookies.js:3:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Generic User\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "request"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.6
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND

npm ERR! Cannot find module 'tough-cookie'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

You probably will tell me to run

```
> npm update -g npm
```

I get the same error for this command too.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your version 3 npm install is broken, for some reason. It'd be interesting to know whether this path exists:

```
C:\Users\Generic User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\node_modules\tough-cookie
```

and whether it contains a valid package, etc.

With your npm v 3 install, broken, none of the npm `install` or `update` commands will work (as they'll need the `request` module). However, you might be able to roll back npm - as version 4.5.0 of Node.js installs npm version 2.15.9 and it will still be there:

```
> npm uninstall -g npm
```

That should leave you with:

```
> npm -v
2.15.9
```

Before re-installing npm v 3, clear the cache:

```
> npm cache clear
> npm install -g npm
```

However, before you re-install version npm v 3, it would be interesting to see if you are able to install `request` with npm v 2.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was a .lock file that caused this error, deleting the file fixed it. Same problem and solution was reported here: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2019

Answer (score 1):

Is there a package.json file in the folder you are running node from?

If there is a package.json, then running :

```
npm install request
```

will not have the desired effect, in fact npm will just try and install whatever module is described in package.json

Comment: I have tried to run same command with and without the existence of the package.json. I always getthe same error

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `npm install tough-cookie`
it has worked for me

Answer (score -2):

its browser issue ... please try to open it in chrome incognito windows or firefox private window  and delete cookies

Comment: This is totally unrelated. This is a question about `node` / `npm`, no browser or website involved.

Comment: cannot find module "tough-cookie" its run time error , 
i research for 1 week and nothing appear to fix the error so i decide to do it like t his way test my app at private window using firefox so the app running normally so when i remove cookies from chrome browser  the app run normally !!!